# How to install rgdal package in R with non system-wide gdal installation

Tags: r, installation, package, rgdal

I'm on a Linux machine with no administration rights and I need to install rgdal package. I have compiled gdal from source and installed it in a custom folder where I have rights to access. 
When I try to install rgdal with:

```
install.packages("rgdal", lib = "libs")
```

I get:

```
* installing *source* package ‘rgdal’ ...
** package ‘rgdal’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
ERROR: 'configure' exists but is not executable -- see the 'R Installation and Administration Manual'
```

This is because it looks for a system-wide gdal (dev) installation. How can I specify that my gdal is installed elsewhere?

I have tried adding:

```
configure.args = "--libdir=/home/user/opt/gdal"
```

but to no avail.

Thanks

---

### Edit 2019-04-16 based on discussion in comments

`libgdal-dev` now installed by sysadmin. Still receiving the following error when trying to install `rgdal`:

```
 * installing source package ‘rgdal’ ... 
** package ‘rgdal’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked ERROR: 'configure' exists but is not executable -- see the 'R Installation and Administration Manual' 
* removing ‘/home/leomarg/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/rgdal’ 
Warning in install.packages : installation of package ‘rgdal’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: Try `--with-gdal-config=/home/user/opt/gdal`?

Comment: Thanks, that didn't work either.

Comment: This was the best resource I found: https://github.com/cran/rgdal/tree/master/inst I made some progress with `install.packages("rgdal", configure.args = "--with-gdal-config=/path/to/gdal-config")` (use `which gdal-config` in terminal to find it)

Comment: Tried again with 
install.packages("rgdal", type = "source", configure.args ="--with-gdal-config=/home/user/opt/gdal/bin/gdal-config") but got still same error message. But I'm now realizing it's probably some other issue, because I had my sys admin install libgdal-dev and could not compile either. So, your solution is probably the right one for the problem as it was exposed, but I should look into the problem from another angle. Not sure what to do now, should I mark your solution as valid, or my question as invalid, or..?

Comment: So, here are the packages that I have: $ apt list --installed | grep libgdal*
libgdal-dev/xenial,now 2.2.2+dfsg-1~xenial1 amd64 [installed]
libgdal1i/xenial,now 1.11.3+dfsg-3build2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libgdal20/xenial,now 2.2.2+dfsg-1~xenial1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libgdata-common/xenial,now 0.17.4-1 all [installed,automatic]
libgdata22/xenial,now 0.17.4-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]

Comment: And this is the error I get:   * installing *source* package ‘rgdal’ ...
** package ‘rgdal’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
ERROR: 'configure' exists but is not executable -- see the 'R Installation and Administration Manual'
* removing ‘/home/leomarg/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/rgdal’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rgdal’ had non-zero exit status

Answer (score 0):

It may be that your `/tmp` directory does not have necessary execute permissions.

Create a user-specific `tmp` directory and add it to your path:

```
mkdir ~/tmp
export TMPDIR=~/tmp
```

Source: https://www.r-bloggers.com/using-r-package-installation-problems/

Comment: No need to do that, destdir parameter can be used to specify the download folder. However that didn't solve the issue. Thanks for trying.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm out of suggestions!